# window.onmousemove in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The purpose of the following code is that when the user is holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key down, some text will indicate that they are pressing it. It works great in Firefox, but IE does not acknowledge it.

```
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var copyLabel = document.getElementById("<%= lblCopyEnabled.ClientID %>");
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            copyLabel.style.display = "inline";
            ob_copyOnNodeDrop = true;
        }
        else {
            copyLabel.style.display = "none";
            ob_copyOnNodeDrop = false;
        }
    }
```

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: What version of IE are you targeting?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Despite what the MSDN docs say, `onmousemove` doesn't work when applied to the `window` object.  It should work in all browsers if you apply it to the `document` object instead:

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var copyLabel = document.getElementById("<%= lblCopyEnabled.ClientID %>");
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        copyLabel.style.display = "inline";
        ob_copyOnNodeDrop = true;
    }
    else {
        copyLabel.style.display = "none";
        ob_copyOnNodeDrop = false;
    }
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/aUxSz/**